# Facebook Share embed score in image - PhoneGap

Tags: phonegap-plugins, image-manipulation, facebook-social-plugins

Some games offer a share feature with the score embedded in an image, like seen below from the game merged:

[image]
[image]

I can't find a reasonable way to create the image with PhoneGap. Should I create a canvas and then  embed the score and then convert it into an image? I already have the share function down using the SocialShare plugin, I just need to create the image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question. Perhaps you can find some cloud service that can merge the images for you, otherwise use something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL